# How to programmatically silence the ringer or change the ringer tone on iOS5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, ringtone

Is there a way to reduce the volume of the ringer or change the ringer tone on iOS5?

I checked out the Celestial framework, but can't instantiate AVSystemController. :-(

I don't care if this get's the app rejected in the AppStore as it will never be submitted.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. Use `AVSystemController`. You don't instantiate it. It's a singleton.

http://code.google.com/p/iphone-dev/source/browse/trunk/include/include/Celestial/AVSystemController.h?r=136

```
[[AVSystemController sharedAVSystemController] setVolumeTo:10.0 forCategory:@"Ringtone"];
```

Comment: Could you provide an example, please?

Comment: I tried including the file you linked, but I get the following error: Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVSystemController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FRRViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

Besides, there's not setVolumeTo:forCategory: method in the linked file.

Comment: It simply may not exist in the simulator — have you tested on device? You could use `[[NSClassFromString(@"AVSystemController") sharedAVSystemController]...` to produce code that works either way if that's the cause.

Comment: You have to link against the Celestial framework. Or you can do what Tommy suggested if you want to avoid linking against it.

Comment: And `setVolumeTo:forCategory:` does exist. The file I linked to is old. Maybe from iOS 3. `setVolumeTo:forCategory:` is available in iOS 4 and 5 I think.

Comment: @tommy I had already tried what you suggested, but [[NSClassFromString(@"AVSystemController") sharedAVSystemController] always returns nil, both on the simulator and the device (iPhone 4 on iOS 5).

Comment: @Fernando I have used that exact code, and it works fine. Also, it won't work on the simulator, only an actual device.

Comment: This approach is working well for me. Where can I find a list of supported categories though? So far I'm only aware of "Ringtone" and "UserInterfaceSoundEffects".

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for: [Override ringer volume in iPhone apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028120/override-ringer-volume-in-iphone-apps/1087046#1087046)

Basically, you set the volume using AVAudioPlayer on the -(void)viewDidLoad method of the view you are displaying on