# Manipulating the ring tone

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to programmatically silence the ringer or change the ringer tone on iOS5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320725/how-to-programmatically-silence-the-ringer-or-change-the-ringer-tone-on-ios5)

Is it possible to turn-on/off the ring tone via code?

Is it possible to change the ring-tone from one to another ring tone via code?

If so, could someone nice provide some sort of reference?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I have only been looking around the internet for an answer i understand but not found anything yet! Black Frog: I am pretty new to this, and not english speaking so i have even a problem formulating the question in english!

Comment: Will this be accepted in AppStore?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740528/play-sound-on-iphone-even-in-silent-mode