# Iphone App auto volume

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to have an iphone app that:

- Allows you to silence phone and automatically turn ringer back on after a set amount of time?

Or

- Lowers ringer volume to 0 and then automatically turn ringer back up after a set amount of time?

Thanks, All answers will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post:

[How to programmatically silence the ringer or change the ringer tone on iOS5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320725/how-to-programmatically-silence-the-ringer-or-change-the-ringer-tone-on-ios5)