# How to lower / silence the ringer in the background

Tags: ios, swift, background

I am trying to make an app that will silence your phone in the background. The purpose of the app is to silence your phone when you are at a certain location. How would I do this in **SWIFT 3**? I am pretty sure I have seen an app on the app store that does this, but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically silence the ringer or change the ringer tone on iOS5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320725/how-to-programmatically-silence-the-ringer-or-change-the-ringer-tone-on-ios5)

Comment: My question is in **SWIFT**  so it is not a duplicate of How to programmatically silence the ringer or change the ringer tone on iOS5 – Ashutosh Dave because that is in objective-c

Comment: The question asked was not the question answered. The person asked how to silence the device and the person showed him how to vibrate the phone -  Ashutosh Dave

Comment: AVSystemController.shared().setVolumeTo(10.0, forCategory: "Ringtone")

Comment: How do I access AVSystemController? – Sahil Manchanda