# iPhone how to override default settings programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, iphone-vibrate

In iPhone, how to override default setting of vibrate and sound programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that unless your doing it for a jailbroken device. Apple will not accept programmatically changing the phone settings. This is ultimately user preference.

Answer (score 0):

I think You cannot(May be Possible if your application is run on a jailbroken device). Because there is no Apple API to access the iPhone settings. But you can Change the setting in your app Bundle.For Vibration You can Go with

```
 #import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>
```

and use

```
 AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

for Volume you can Go with

```
AVSystemController

[[AVSystemController sharedAVSystemController] setVolumeTo:10.0 forCategory:@"Ringtone"];
```

[Try this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028120/override-ringer-volume-in-iphone-apps/1087046#1087046)
and the Best will be however use [MPVolumeView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (volume slider) is there to change device volume but only through user interaction.

MPVolumeView is a control in toolbox, you need to add MediaPlayer.framework in your project then MPVolumeView will be displayed in toolbox in interface builder.