# Need the ringer volume, getting the iPod volume

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, mpmusicplayercontroller

I need to know (and control) my sound volume. I get it like this:

```
float volume = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] outputVolume];
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"MPVolumeView volume = %3.2f", volume]);
```

The float that prints is the volume that is set in my iPod. If I use the up and down volume buttons I see the volume overlay showing the correct ringer volume, not the iPod volume. Using the applicationMusicPlayer doesn't work either

```
float volume = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer].volume;
```

This even happens in a sample app, the above lines are the only lines of code that I added to the stock "single view" project.

I only need an iOS6 solution but hey, if it works in older version I won't complain. Thanks!

Comment: Toggle *Settings > Sounds > 'Change with Buttons' :)*

Comment: I can't ask my entire user base to change that...

Comment: yes and no... When I use the side buttons the app now prints the side button volume but it has also changed the iPod volume.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's just an iOS limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check: [Override ringer volume in iPhone apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028120/override-ringer-volume-in-iphone-apps/1087046#1087046)

Add a dummy AVAudioPlayer and load it with a sound. Then just call prepareToPlay. Now you don't change the ringer anymore with the buttons.

Seems the app Waze is also doing this.

Comment: Talk about reviving an old unanswered question! Marked as correct even though I no longer have the source code to test it on, just to reward good behavior.